# Javascript - Unify between objects values within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

How can I unify between objects values within an array that have same key using javascript?

for example if i have this array:

```
0: {key: 'abc1', value: 'product1'}
1: {key: 'abc2', value: "product2"}
2: {key: 'abc2', value: 'product3'}
```

and i want result array to be like that:

```
  0: {key: 'abc1', value: 'product1'}
  1: {key: 'abc2', value: "product2, product3"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another performant solution:

```js
const data = [
    { key: "abc1", value: "product1" },
    { key: "abc2", value: "product2" },
    { key: "abc2", value: "product3" },
];

const output = Object.values(
    data.reduce((carry, item) => {
        const key = item.key;
        if (carry[key]) {
            carry[key].value += `, ${item.value}`;
        } else {
            carry[key] = item;
        }
        return carry;
    }, {})
);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pretty manual way of doing it, I'm sure there is a more elegant solution, but can't think of one off the top of my head.

```js
val = [
  {key: 'abc1', value: 'product1'},
  {key: 'abc2', value: 'product2'},
  {key: 'abc2', value: 'product3'}
];

newVal = [];

val.forEach((objToAdd)=>{
    let match = newVal.find((obj)=>obj.key===objToAdd.key);
    if(match){
        match.value=`${match.value}, ${objToAdd.value}`;
    } else {
        newVal.push(objToAdd);
    }
});

console.log(newVal);
```

Comment: I leave my answer for your reference. You actually can use `hashmap` instead of `find` in the forEach loop. That way would be more efficient. Then, you can retrieve all the data back by `Object.values`